# GDAL: jp2 driver missing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal

I need to open .jp2 raster files in python.

i installed GDAL following [these instructions](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/).

Using the command line running `gdalinfo --formats` lists the `JP2OpenJPEG` driver. `gdalinfo filename.jp2` returns the expected output.

But in python

`import gdal 
data=gdal.Open('filename.jp2')`

does not return anything (.tiff works).

There are 2 other applications using GDAL installed so I assume python is using the wrong GDAL installation.

I have the same problem in R but there i can point out the right installation with 

`library(gdalUtils)
gdal_chooseInstallation('JP2OpenJPEG')`

Is there a way to point python to the right installation or add the driver for jp2?

---

Windows 10

Python 2.7

GDAL 2.1.0

Comment: Hi, might be a long shot, but did you get the R package rgdal to use another local installation of gdal?

Comment: gdal_chooseInstallation()  from the package gdalUtils

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same platform and was facing the same issue.

I think i found a workaround for this:

Install OSGEO4W https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ this will install GDAL with the JP2 drivers.

Set up your environment variables correctly. Have a look at what OSGEO does in bin\O4W_ENV.bat make sure you add these to your Path variable `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\WBem`
**The order matters**, make sure you have them in this order in the PATH variable otherwise you might have issues.

To test do `gdalinfo --format JP2OpenJPEG`

Since anaconda can mess with the PATH variable i add the osgeo home in my script again.

`# set environment
    osgeo_home_bin = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin"
    # the path order matters so make sure OSGEO4W64 is the first one
    os.environ['PATH'] = ''.join([osgeo_home_bin,";",os.environ['PATH']])`

Comment: thanks for your contribution. I have got the jp2 driver by reinstalling gdal as explained above. the problem is that it's not accessible through python.

Comment: how does your PATH variable look like ? make sore the %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin; is at the front, when i launch anaconda it messes with the path variable so i have to add it back again in my python script like this # set environment
    `osgeo_home_bin = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin"
    # the path order matters so make sore OSGEO4W64 is the first one
    os.environ['PATH'] = ''.join([osgeo_home_bin,";",os.environ['PATH']])`